# Raspberry Pi Executables and Redirection

Tags: linux

I have an executable that I am running on the Raspberry Pi. When the program is run, output is displayed on the terminal, but when I use the redirect operator `>`, I get nothing in the text file.

```
./example > examp.txt
```

I have also tried using the pipe operator and the `tee` command but when I do this I get nothing in the text file or on the screen. I am unsure what to try next. The output from the executable is a data stream that is updated every few seconds. I would like to capture a couple updates from the executable in a text file.

```
./example | tee examp.txt
```

Comment: Does the file exist already and is writable by the user executing the executable? With `>>` you can append text to a file, a single `>` overwrites the file (so there's a chance that you overwrite the text with a blank line).

Answer (score 4):

Your executable might be writing to stderr instead of stdout.  So it might be worth trying to redirect stdout, e.g.,

```
./example 2> stderr.txt > stdout.txt # write stdout and stderr to two different files
```

or

```
./example 2>&1 > log.txt # redirect stderr to stdout and then write them together into one
```

file

Further, your executable might not be writing to either stderr and stdout, e.g., by writing directly to the screen using a library such as curses.  In that case, you won't be able to capture its output.  It might be worth however to study the executable's documentation if you can give it a command line switch to write to stdout/stderr instead of directly to the screen interactively.  An example would be the `top` command in Linux systems, where you can supply a command line option `-b`.